# Rikulo - touchEnd check if ended inside bounds

Tags: dart, rikulo

When "listening" to `touchEnd` event of a `View`, how can I determine weather the touch ended inside it's bounds?
in other words, the equivalent of the iOS `touchUpInside`.

Note-
I'm adding a `touchEnd` handler and not only `on.click` because iOS devices have this 300 ms intentional delay and I would like to eliminate it (please point out if there is a better solution to this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the event handling, Rikulo UI doesn't handle specially but adding a thin layer on top of what [Dart API](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.Element) provides. After all, a view is simply a DIV element with some special attributes.

Here is the list of events we wrapped: [Rikulo events](http://api.rikulo.org/ui/latest/rikulo_event/ViewEvents.html). If there is a miss, please let us know (by posting an issue to [Github](https://github.com/rikulo/ui)).

Regarding simulation of touchUpInside, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535441/is-there-a-way-to-touchendinside-in-mobile-safari) might help.